# gzip.open() function in python

Tags: python, gzip

I am learning ML and I am stuck with this following line of code

**can anyone help me yo know what does this line of does**

and the parameters required to give for it are??

`gzip.open('../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open

Answer (score 1):

It starts to upload to memory the file you adressed in binary mode(fast way of reading), mostly you have to use rb argument.
Next step is modifying this data and writing it back with 'wb' command.